# Two way data binding for checkbox in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to use checkboxes in one column of the ag-grid.

```
ColumDefe={
     headername: "",
     Field:"active", 
     Cellrenderer: function(params){
        return `<input type="checkbox" ${ params.value ? 'checked':' '}  />`
     }
}
```

By doing this I can achieve only one way data binding but cannot achieve two way data binding ... When I unchecked the checkbox it is not changing the value of the active field....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cellEditor` component for that.

As per [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) documentation,

> Cell Renderer's are for displaying data and Cell Editors are for editing data. If your application is for showing data only, such as a reporting application, then you will not need to use cell editors. If you are editing your data like a spreadsheet, then you will need Cell Editors to do the editing.

Reference: [Cell editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/)